# Zend View Helper - Dependent Files, Images, CSS, JS

Tags: zend-framework

What is the best way to structure or package a view helper that will display a reusable flash chart based on passed data?

Should the structure looks something like this, or is it overkill? I would like to keep the files separate from the general public app files.

-application
---module
----default
------views
--------helpers
----------MyFlashChart.php
-public
---images
---css
---js
***---default***

------views
--------helpers
----------MyFlashChart
------------js
------------css
------------images
------------swf

I guess technically I will be using a partial in combination..

Comment: it may not be a good idea to put server side scripts (PHP) in the public folder. Put the PHP files in the library and then just include the public data as needed and store them in whatever way is comfortable.

Comment: my question is where to put the images, css, js, matching the structure/location of the helper. yes i know the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html